# Versioning Entity By Inserting en New Entity With Version Using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm looking for a solution in order to perform some "Entity History".
Basically i've a domain like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }

    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public virtual int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}
```

I need to keep history of these entities in order to prevent from dependent entities updates like product changes (names, etc..)

So i want to create a new entity on each save/update with an updated version number.

My repository method GetOrderById should take care of entity versions and take the latest version or a specific version if specified.

How can i perform that? Maybe using NHibernate Interceptors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use evenlisteners. You can use it to get different behavior for the loads and save/delete/updates.

[Eventlisteners for data audit](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-11-interceptors-and/1nr4enxv3dpeq/14#view)

Answer (score 0):

```
<version name="Version" column="Version" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" type="Int64"/>
```

It would be best to have versioning implemented on the root object

[Concurrency](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and-concurrency)

[Version](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version)